# How to give more priority to Facebook ads in Admob facebook mediation?

Tags: facebook-audience-network

I am integrating ads into android. I have integrated Admob using google tutorial. Now, I want to use Admob with Facebook mediation. I want to set priority to FAN. How can I put it in my project?

Answer (score -1):

[Create mediation group](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7374967?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)s and set higher [priority](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3063564?visit_id=637943406883988757-4008790580&rd=1#priority) to Facebook Ads.

[image]

**Note**: the highest priority is `1`

Comment: @roman the question didn't specify!